# ParentId gone on Azure Function after upgrade to V3 and .net core 3.1

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I just upgraded an app service to .net core 3.1 from 2.2 and a function to V3 from V2.
The app service puts a message on a queue that is then picked up and processed by the function(ServiceBusTrigger).

Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extensions.ServiceBus 3.0.6 -> 4.1.1,
Microsoft.Sdk.Functions 1.0.29 -> 3.0.5, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.10.0 -> 2.13.1

We changed the AzurefunctionsVersion to v3 in the .csproj and the FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to ~3.

Before the upgrade the end-to-end scenario in application insights was complete showing met the whole flow from receiving the message, posting it to the queue and then when the function picked it up. The parentId of the function is here a reference to the initial request.

[image]

After the upgrade the parentId of the function is the same as operationId and no reference to any parent which means the end-to-end scenario from the initial request stops after the message has been put on the queue.

[image]

If I want to see what happened in the function I need to locate that in application insights separately.

Is there anything I need to do in the latest version to make everything work that wasn't needed before?

Comment: Can you provide a sample code for that?

Comment: We don't have any code to set any ids anywhere. Application Insights managed to keep everything together anyway..up until now that is.

Comment: The code I mean if the azure function is a simple queue trigger one? and you mentioned it's upgraded to v3, how did you upgrade? how about directly creating a v3 function?

Comment: I added som more info.